# Is there a way to include Android unit test as JMeter Sampler?

Tags: android, unit-testing, jmeter, load-testing

I'm new with JMeter load testing.

Is there a way to include Android unit test as JMeter Sampler?

I know we can add .Jar files and JMeter can detect the unit tests included, so is there a way to do the same thing for Android app? like adding .apk file?

Answer (score 0):

Not for the unit tests, if you intend to run an unit tests with multiple thread/iterations on the Android device/emulator you should rather consider using a [microbenchmarking library](https://brightinventions.pl/blog/microbenchmarking-on-android) like [androidx.benchmark](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/benchmark)

The only valid use case of JMeter when it comes to Android applications testing is simulating network traffic of hundreds/thousands of mobile devices to load test the **backend**, if this is something you're looking for as well I would recommend getting familiarized with [Load Testing Mobile Apps Made Easy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy) article